# Convert JsonNode to list<Object[]>

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON like below.

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "screenId": "abc456",
  "name": "Screen1",
  "description": "screen description",
  "format": [
    {
      "sectionName": "fontType",
      "font": {
        "family": {
          "id": "TIMESNEWROMAN",
          "description": "TIMESNEWROMAN"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "sectionName": "backgroundColorPanel",
      "color": "#000000"
    },
    {
      "sectionName": "buttonBorderShape",
      "shape": {
        "color": "#000000",
        "type": {
          "id": "SOLID",
          "description": "Solid"
        },
        "size": "12"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following code to convert it into `List<Object[]>` but I am getting the exception

code:

```
JsonNode node =  mapper.readTree(jsonString);
TypeReference<List<Object[]>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<Object[]>>(){};
List<Object> list = mapper.readValue(node.traverse(), typeRef);
```

exception:

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
```

I also tried the following

```
mapper.readValue(mapper.treeAsTokens(jsonString), TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, Object[].class))
```

But I am getting the same exception. Can someone help me?